# Can I use htaccess to invisibly redirect one domain to a subdomain on another domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

I've been pulling my hair out trying to research this and find out if this is possible. Any help would be appreciated.

I have two domains. Let's call them foo.com and bar.com. I only have one web server, so right now, they're pointing to the same place.

I have a separate site set up at bar.foo.com.

I want all visits to bar.com to go to bar.foo.com, but still say "bar.com" in the browser's address bar.

Here's what I've got in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bar.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://foo.bar.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This successfully redirects it, but, you end up seeing "foo.bar.com" in the address bar.

Using htaccess, can I get this redirect to happen "invisibly", so that if the user types in "bar.com", they will still see "bar.com" in the browser?

I don't have access to the apache config files on the server, so I'm limited to what I can put in a htaccess file.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the 2 domains served by the same document root?

Comment: Hi Jon. No, at the moment, foo is pointing to /www/www and bar is pointing to /www/bar

Comment: do you have access to vhost or server config?

Comment: No. Unfortunately I only have access to the htaccess file. Does this mean I can't do what I want?